# jQuery Advance Selector Using Wildcards

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, wildcard

I have an input element which id looks like:

```
Les_Site_1381400656_43306_input
```

The ID format will always be Les_Site_ANYTHING_INPUT

My current selector is: `$(element).find('[id^=Les_Site_input]')`

How do I i make a selector which says i want this at the start anything in the middle and this at the end?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// starts with "Les_Site_" , ends with "_input" :
$(element).find('[id^=Les_Site_][id$=_input]')
```

Note that such filtering rules are slow, you want to call them on as few elements as possible :

```
$(element).find('input').filter('[id^=Les_Site_][id$=_input]')
```

The way you seem to be using ids : you would have a better time adding a `class` to this input, and select it using that class

```
<input class="siteInput" id="Les_Site_1381400656_43306_input" />

$(element).find('input.siteInput')
```